# Security predicate in einstein analytics

Tags: einstein-analytics

I want to create a security predicate such that the reporting office in dataset is equal to reporting office on current user's contact.

'DataSetName.fieldName' == "$Users.Contact.Region__C.name"

I tried this but it is not working?
So can anyone please tell me that how to access lookup on user in security predicate

Answer (score 0):

You can only use User object fields and not any lookup/relations field that are present on User, here in your example it looks like you are trying to access a Contact's Region which has a lookup on User object, if that Region field would have been on User object that would have work fine.
Something like this :
'DataSetName.fieldName' == "$Users.Region__C"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).